# How do I condense my git log output by "de-duplicating" branch names (as described below)?

Tags: git, git-log

I would like to display my `git log` so that branch names are "de-duplicated"—so that the same branch on *origin* does not need its full name displayed next to the local name.

For example, here is what I currently have as the first line of my `git log --graph`:

```
* 9c202db5 (HEAD -> feature/blah-blah-descriptive-name--289, origin/feature/blah-blah-descriptive-name--289) do the thing to the code
```

But I would like it to become more like this (and this is just an example—whatever achieves the same basic effect would be fine):

```
* 9c202db5 (HEAD -> feature/blah-blah-descriptive-name--289 <-> origin) do the thing to the code
```

(SHA1 shortening here is done for cosmetic purposes, to make the differences visible without scrolling.)

Answer (score 1):

Git has nothing internally to do this.  All it does is remove `refs/heads/` from branch names, and `refs/remotes/` (or sometimes just `refs/`) from remote-tracking names.

You could write your own code that reads `git log` output and edits it.  Note that you will run into the same ambiguity issues that Git itself runs into if you name a branch `origin`.  Internally, Git knows the difference, because `refs/heads/origin` is clearly a branch name—it starts with `refs/heads/`—while `refs/remotes/origin/master` is clearly a remote-tracking name because it starts with `refs/remotes/`.  Externally it becomes difficult to tell what's what.  But you are probably OK with that, just as Git is if you name a (local) branch `origin/master`: just avoid doing that and it's not a problem!